# Component update triggers componentDidUpdate of all of it's children in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am shocked to find out that the update caused in a react component, let's say because of state update will trigger componentDidUpdate of all it's children including grandchildren and may be below that as well(though I have verified only the grandchildren
scenario)

Am I missing anything? what are the "best practices" to check if the component is updated due to it's own props or state in a class component?

App.js:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Child from './child';
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      count: 0,
      obj: {
        key1: 'text',
      }
    };
  }

  clickHandler = () => {
    const tempObj =  {
      key1: 'text',
    };
    this.setState({
      count: 0,
      obj: tempObj,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='container'>
        <div className='top-button'>
        <button onClick={this.clickHandler}>`count: ${this.state.count}`</button>;
        </div>
        <Child />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

child.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Grandchild from './grandchild';
class Child extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(){
    console.log('child: component updated');
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    console.log('child mounted');
  }

  render() {
    return <Grandchild />;
  }
}

export default Child;
```

grandchild.js

```
import React from 'react';

class Grandchild extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(){
    console.log('Grandchild: component updated');
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    console.log('Grandchild mounted');
  }
  
  render() {
    return null;
  }
}

export default Grandchild;
```

Comment: This is expected behavior in React -> componentDidUpdate is supposed to trigger for all the 'children' if the parent is.  What exactly is your question about it?

Comment: what are the "best practices" to check if the component is updated due to it's own props or state in a class component?